# Wrong characters in serial console

Tags: networking, putty, switch, serial

I have a Linksys SRW2048 that I want to configure via the serial port. I hooked it up with an RS232 / USB cable and a gender changer on the RS232 end. If I start a PuTTy session (same Problem in other software) then there are a lot of characters wrong.

[command line output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlVhe.png)

[PuTTy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzRpf.png)

The settings should be right, set like in the manual.

Comment: Try a slower speed (19.2) and see if that helps.

Comment: Also make sure you have the correct cable:  https://community.cisco.com/t5/small-business-switches/console-cable-for-srw2048/td-p/2190024

Comment: @John slower speed only makes it worse (same as higher) and i have a normal RS232-USB Cable with Pl2303 Chip, which is working, because i already used it on other switche. Just the gender changer can be a problem, but i´m gonna try it with jumper cable instead of it.

Comment: There may be intermittent contact issues in the gender changer (new information). Try without.